# LibGit2 SSH Authenication Failing

Tags: c++, ssh, libgit2

I'm trying to clone a repository using SSH with LibGit2 using this code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"
#include "git2.h"

using namespace std;

int creds(git_cred **out, const char *url, const char *username_from_url,
             unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload) {
    cout << "Calling creds" << endl;
    return git_credential_ssh_key_new(out, username_from_url,
            "path_to_home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", "path_to_home/.ssh/id_rsa", "password");
}

int main() {
    git_libgit2_init();
    string url = "git@github.com:Black-Photon/Git-Testing.git";

    git_repository *repo = nullptr;
    git_clone_options ops = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    ops.fetch_opts.callbacks.credentials = creds;

    int err = git_clone(&repo, url.c_str(), "path_to_home/Documents/temp/Git-Testing", &ops);
    cout << giterr_last()->message << endl;

    git_libgit2_shutdown();
}
```

However the output I get is:

```
Calling creds
Calling creds
Calling creds
...
```

Suggesting it isn't accepting the SSH key and password. However when I use the same key and password in ordinary Git:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:Black-Photon/Git-Testing.git
Cloning into 'Git-Testing'...
Enter passphrase for key 'path_to_home/.ssh/id_rsa': password
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
remote: Total 29 (delta 0), reused 13 (delta 0), pack-reused 6
Receiving objects: 100% (29/29), 4.58 KiB | 426.00 KiB/s, done.
```

It works normally. Why is it failing using LibGit2?

I'm using LibGit2 version 0.99.0. I have tried with both a kept and removed empty last line in `id_rsa` and previously on LibGit2 version 0.26.0 gave a different message: `Failed to authenticate SSH session: Callback returned error`. I have also tried using 
`git_credential_ssh_key_memory_new` with the same results.

Comment: You might be able to get additional information about the failure using `git_error_last()` in the callback itself, after trying to load the key. Do note that some PEM formats aren't actually supported by libssh2's underlying crypto backend — either OpenSSL (which supports most things), mbedTLS, or gcrypt — but RSA ought to be fine.

Comment: Both `giterr_last()` and `git_error_last()` return 0 after running `git_credential_ssh_key_new`.

The command I used to generate the key was the one on the Github website: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH library being used, 1.8.0, is outdated and must be updated to 1.9.0.